# Android TelephonyManager requestCellInfoUpdate returning old timeStamp but data was changed

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I update allCellInfo in Android 10 and higher with requestCellInfoUpdate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            tm.requestCellInfoUpdate(
                context.mainExecutor,
                object : TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback() {
                    override fun onCellInfo(activeCellInfo: MutableList<CellInfo>) {
                        
                    }
                })
        }
```

Why the activeCellInfos timestamps stay old but data (rssi, rsrp, rsrq and etc) changes?